# Periodic Batch processing as separate microservice

Tags: microservices

I have huge legacy monolith with dozen of periodic background thread that each background thread wakes every X (configurable) time and do some batch processing from data present in DB.

As part of our refactoring towards microservices is it a good idea to make each background task as separate microservice? each background task will be waken do its job and then disappear until next time

For the tech stack the monolith in written in pure Java and microservices that supposed to the the batch processing every X unit of time projected to be written using Spring Batch

Comment: The question I would ask is, what "service" would the microservice provide, beyond what Spring Batch already gives you?

Comment: Nothing. It just do the logic of batch processing with the aid of Spring batch framework

Comment: So I'd say if you've got nothing to gain by making the batch jobs microservices, what Spring Batch gives you should be enough.   Addition through subtraction!